# is it possible to use .stopPropagation() on .trigger() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use the `.trigger()`-event together with `.stopPropagation()` ? I need to simulate a submit event without triggering the submit event.

```
$('.form .submit').trigger('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

does not work. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: No, you need to put `stopPropagation()` within the event handler, not the trigger.

Comment: Also, `I need to simulate a submit event without triggering the submit event` makes no sense. Could you describe what you need to achieve, as I'm sure there's a better way

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok right, the description is actually a bit bad. I need to initiate a function, so I can run another function

Comment: If you use `e.preventDefault()` and `.submit` is actually a `input[type="submit"]` (don't know for certian there's no HTML), then there would only be a `click` event and no `submit` event. It makes no sense to do this ...but yeah...

Comment: @Steve Wait, but then why don't you call the function you want to call?!... I guess if only you have provided a minimalistic sample, it would be easier to catch your expected behaviour. Actually, just sounds like a XY problem imho

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) method:

```
$('.form .submit').triggerHandler('click');
```

> The .triggerHandler( "event" ) method will not call .event() on the
>   element it is triggered on. This means .triggerHandler( "submit" ) on
>   a form will not call .submit() on the form.

And more specific to your case:

> Events triggered with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM
>   hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly,
>   they do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you say what happens in your submit event?
until now i would say something like this:

```
// add trigger for submit event
$( ".form" ).on( "submit", function( e, prevent ) {
    if ( prevent ) {
        // stop propagation if second argument named prevent was committed
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
} );
// trigger Event "submit"
// use $.Event to ensure that the native submit event of the form will be called
// set a second parameter as list with the first index true to set this as second argument in the eventHandler
// third argument would be the second index in the array
$( ".form" ).trigger( $.Event( "submit" ), [ true ] );
```

Comment: Why do you pass the `true` as an array if you only test as boolean? Just pass it as bool and keep things simple

Comment: It is passes as array because it will be handled with `Function.ptototype.apply`. Just have a look here : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Ahh. That comment might be a valuable add to your answer itself :) Understanding *why* you do things is as important as the how IMO :)

Comment: I don't understand... you want me to edit the answer adding the info? :)

Comment: I try to add small comments/info snippets in my answers for the somewhat more advanced code. This way a beginner can just copy it, but an advanced user can learn the *why* as well

Comment: I hope you will enjoy :D